# Hit object toward MousePosition in unity 2d pool game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making 2d pool game in Unity, and I can't hit the ball towards the mouse position in the game! When the user makes direction of mouse toward hitting ball, it should hit it, like a usual pool game.

Here is my C# code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class whiteBall : MonoBehaviour {

    Rigidbody2D rb;
    int speed;
    public GameObject ball;
    public GameObject cue;

    Vector3 mousePos;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        speed = 10;
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "pockets")
        {
            Debug.Log("Game collision with pockets");
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {       
        hitBall();

        mousePos = Input.mousePosition;

        // mouse move cordianates
        Vector3 objectPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
        mousePos.x = mousePos.x - objectPos.x;
        mousePos.y = mousePos.y - objectPos.y;

        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(mousePos.y, mousePos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0,0,angle));
    }

    public void hitBall()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            Vector2 newPos = new Vector2(Mathf.Abs(mousePos.x), Mathf.Abs(mousePos.y));

            rb.AddForce(newPos * 20 * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            Debug.Log(newPos);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there anyone who can answer to my Question ? :)

Comment: Here's a tip, try with raycast. Shoot raycast from the tip of the pool stick to the mouse position or even better just shoot it in forward and rotate the rotate the stick to mouse position, also make the length of the raycast long enough to reach every point of the table. When raycast hit the ball object, calculate hit angle and then apply force.

Check this link for angles: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KXk_VPgZrWk

Comment: Thanks for help!